# templated typedef?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

I'm using libgc, a garbage collector for C and C++.
To make STL containers garbage collectible one must use the gc_allocator.

Instead of writing

```
std::vector<MyType>
```

one has to write

```
std::vector<MyType,gc_allocator<MyType> >
```

Could there be a way to define something like

```
template<class T> typedef std::vector<T,gc_allocator<T> > gc_vector<T>;
```

I checked some time ago and found out it was not possible. But I may have been wrong or there might be another way around.

Defining maps in this way is particularly unpleasing.

```
std::map<Key,Val>
```

becomes

```
std::map<Key,Val, std::less<Key>, gc_allocator< std::pair<const Key, Val> > >
```

EDIT: After trying the use of macro I found out the following code breaks it:

```
#define gc_vector(T) std::vector<T, gc_allocator<T> >
typedef gc_vector( std::pair< int, float > ) MyVector;
```

The comma inside the templated type definition is interpreted as a macro argument separator.

So it seems the inner class/struct is the best solution.

Here is an example on how it will be done in C++0X

```
// standard vector using my allocator
template<class T>
using gc_vector = std::vector<T, gc_allocator<T> >;

// allocates elements using My_alloc
gc_vector <double> fib = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };

// verbose and fib are of the same type
vector<int, gc_vector <int>> verbose = fib;
```

Comment: why do you say that the `TypeHelper` solution requires you to redefine constructors? It's nothing more than a shortcut on a typedef...

Comment: Oops, you are right. It's good you clarified this in your answer.

I was told that C++0X will provide a better solution by use of the 'using' keyword. Do you know how this would work ?

Comment: C++0x will provide template aliases, which will provide a way to do exactly what you want. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2258.pdf

Comment: @WurmD which updated answer ? I changed the accepted answer to the one providing the C++11 method. Is that what you asked me ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use C++11 templated type aliasing using `using` e.g. like this

```
template <typename T>
using gc_vector = std::vector<T, gc_allocator<T>>;
```

<sub>Note: I know this is an old question but since it has quite many upvotes and as it turns up in search results I thought it deserved an updated answer.</sub>

Answer (score 37):

You cannot use a "templated typedef", but you can use a convenience class/struct with an inner type:

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeHelper{
    typedef std::vector<T,gc_allocator<T> > Vector;
};
```

and then use in your code

```
TypeHelper<MyType>::Vector v;
TypeHelper<MyType>::Vector::iterator it;
```

And something similar for the map:

```
template<typename K,typename V>
struct MapHelper{
    typedef std::map<K, V, gc_allocator<K,V> > Map;
};
```

EDIT - @Vijay: I don't know if there's another possible workaround, that's how I would do it; a macro might give you a more compact notation, but personally I wouldn't like it:

```
#define GCVECTOR(T) std::vector<T,gc_allocator<T> >
```

EDIT - @chmike: Please note that the `TypeHelper` solution **does not** require you to redefine constructors!

Comment: Yeap, there is. Inheritance is much neater is this very case.

Comment: @sharptooth: it's true that inheritance in this case gives you the best notation and avoids the use of a macro, but its usage is debatable, as pointed out in the comments to your answer.

Comment: I'm patiently waiting for any proof of potential problems.

Comment: I'll pick answer with the macro since it is the "best" solution. Both other solutions (inheritance or inner class/struct) require to redefine constructors. The macro would be used in typedef instructions.

Comment: @sharptooth: You've got proof already. "The standard doesn't guarantee that it'll behave as expected." It might work on every C++ compiler in existence today, but not in the version released next year. If you choose to rely on undefined behavior, that
is your choice, but the burden of proof is yours

Comment: @jalf. Reasonable. Definitely from the "works, but proceed with care" department.

Comment: You could add in your answer that template typedefs (aka template aliases) will be included in C++0x (however, it's not supported by gcc yet) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2258.pdf.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an example.

I also show why the macro method is bogus and should not be used. Learned by experience. ;)

Comment: @Paolo: Useful for an unfortunate circumstance adapting another program's code.  Thanks

Comment: I've inadvertently concocted a name for this pattern: [a metafactory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19187469/1329652) :)

Answer (score 8):

You can publicly inherit:

```
template<class T>
class gc_vector<T> : public std::vector<T, gc_allocator<T> >
{
    public:
    // You'll have to redeclare all std::vector's constructors here so that
    // they just pass arguments to corresponding constructors of std::vector
};
```

This solves your problem completely. The derived type can be used everywhere where the base type can be used, and there's no implementation overhead with any decent compiler.

The fact that std::vector has non-virtual destructor might lead to undefined behaviour according to C++ standard if you ever try to delete a derived class variable through a pointer to base class variable.

In real world this shouldn't matter in this particular case - the derived class has nothing new added compared to the base class and therefore the destructor for the derived class just calls the destructor for the base class. Proceed with paranoia, port carefully anyway.

If you never allocate this class variables on heap (and it's typical to allocate vector variables on stack and as members of other classes) the non-virtual destructor problem doesn't affect you.

Comment: There is the problem that vectors are not designed to be derived from, as they lack a virtual destructor.

Comment: True, but it doesn't matter in this particular case, since the derived type has exactly the same set of meber variables as the base type.

Comment: It matters if he deletes a pointer to a base that points to a derived as he is then off in undefined behaviour land.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter in this case. The derived has no new data members compared to the base, so there's no difference between delete for Base* and Derived*. The derived constructor just calls the base constructor anyway.

Comment: hi sharptooth, what if he creates some memory in the derived constructor and deletes a pointer to a base that points to a derived class. Memory leak isnt it. I think, your solution fits perfectly for the current question, but its not robust.

Comment: Also Sharptooth, please mention that...no fiddling in derived class, i.e no resource acquisition. I vote u up.

Comment: @sharptooth - it does matter - what you suggest may happen, but the standard says it is UB.

Comment: Well, I hope that the standard is not the replacement for logic and common sense. Can you show an example of why this very case may cause problems?

Comment: What about constructors ? 
Regarding memory leaks, note that this is for a garbage collector use. As long as gc_allocator is used, there is no memory leak (assuming specification is correct :) )

Comment: You'll have to redeclare all constructors so that they call corresponding vector's constructors.

Comment: There is no common sense in relying on undefined behavior.  It's inherently unportable regardless of what one implementation happens to do.  So yes, the standard is a replacement for "common sense" in this case.

Comment: Yeap, I completely agree, but I'd like to see an example of what can go wrong in this particular case.

Comment: As long as nothing causes the gc_vector to have a vtable or any data, then this should fall into the 'not to standard, but you can certainly get away with it' category. If anything can cause gc_vector to have data or vtable, then deleting via base pointer is gonna kill you.

Comment: It's hard to give an example of undefined behavior.  A conforming implementation could delete the contents of your hard disk if it felt like it.  If you try it on all reasonable systems and it works as expected, feel free to use it knowing it's undefined.  As a rule, though, I'd steer clear of UB.

Comment: @Michael Not kill, just a memory leak in certain cases.

Comment: The need to redefine constructors (and I guess some typedefs too) in both solutions leads to the conclusion that the macro is the "best" solution.

Comment: Debugging code with macros is much harder compared to code with templates.

Comment: Macros are definitely not the best solution. Avoid themn. I'd go with the struct/typedef wrapper, and suffer the few characters extra typing, but in practice, sharptooths suggestion works too (although I'd only do it if I was sure I'd call the base class' destructor directly.

Comment: @sharptooth, no, he said kill, not memory leak, because that's what might happen. You can't in general be sure that the only function of a destructor is to release allocated memory. It might have important side effects. And so, it might corrupt the app state if the correct dtor is not called.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a MACRO, if you're willing to push your compiler to its limits. I did it while implementing C++ equivalents for Java's "Future" and "Callable" classes. Our library uses reference-counted objects, so "Reference<T>" is itself a template class where "T" derives from "ReferencedObject".

```
1. Create your template Classes. Mine are:

    template<typename T>
    class Callable {
    private:

    public:
        virtual T Call() = 0;
    };

    template<typename T> CountedFuture : public ReferencedObject {
    private:
       Callable<T>* theTask;
       T            theResult;

    public:
       T Get() { 
          // Run task if necessary ...
          if(task) {
             theResult = theTask->Call();
             delete theTask;
          }
          return theResult;
       }
    };

2. In the application code I'm using references, so I define the macro:

   #define Future(T) Reference<CountedFuture<T>>
```

The beauty of this is that is that the Macro does exactly what you'd want from a "template typedef", the downsides being that you can't use "<>" for your type parameter(s) and there is no type inference.

```
3. I can now use the Macro wherever I would use a template, like in functions:

   Future(char*) DoSomething() { ... }
   bool          TestSomething(Future(std::string) f) { .... }
```