# C++ typedef for partial templates

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

i need to do a typedef like this.

```
template< class A, class B, class C >
class X
{
};

template< class B, class C >
typedef X< std::vector<B>, B, C >  Y;
```

I just found that it is not supported in C++. Can someone advise me on how to achieve the same through alternative means?

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: possible duplicate of [templated typedef ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649718/templated-typedef)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have a C++0x/C++1x compiler, that will be allowed with a slightly different syntax (it seems as if compilers don't still support this feature):

```
template <typename B, typename C>
using Y = X< std::vector<B>, B, C >;
```

You can use other techniques, like defining an enclosed type in a templated struct (like Pieter suggests), or abusing inheritance (avoid if possible):

```
template <typename B, typename C>
class Y : public X< std::vector<B>, B, C > {};
```

Comment: It makes me wonder though *why* it is not yet supported. Is it so much harder than move semantics, `auto` typing, variadic templates or some other stuff that at least seems difficult to implement? But I don't have much experience in building a compiler, my intuition on how hard stuff is could be *way* off :).

Comment: I think different parts of the standard were decided on at different times - compiler makers have to be reasonably confident a feature won't change before the final standard comes out in 2011 before they spend time developing it - and then decide how that fits in to their release schedules.

Comment: I am a person of the future.  It seems to be supported in major compilers now.

Comment: I don't see how the second solution abuses inheritance. It exactly fits the idea of inheritance: deriving from one class to create another, more specialized class. Or in this case, deriving from one template to create a more specialized template.

Comment: At first thought, the idea of specializing a template using a typedef seems to make natural sense. But, in fact, it contradicts the idea of a typedef: a type definition. If the type isn't fully defined, then it's not a typedef.

Comment: @orodbhen: A `typedef` does not define a type, it did not in C and it does not in C++, it creates an alias so the rational in the last comment does not stand. The use of inheritance in the answer is really *abuse*. Inheritance is the feature of the language (of many languages) that is most often abused. The use of inheritance there does not create a type to be substitutable in place of the base, but a syntactic shortcut not to type. The problems are too many to put on a comment, but start with constructors (having to forward) and end with destructors (is `X` destructor virtual?)

Answer (score 16):

By placing it in a struct. This idea is called *template alias* and is part of the C++0x standard ([the proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2258.pdf)). But a work-around is given by:

```
template<class B, class C>
struct Y {
  typedef X<std::vector<B>, B, C> type;
};
```

and use `Y<B, C>::type` as your desired type.

And you might be inclined to think gcc4.5 or VS2010 might already support it, as is the case with a big subset of C++0x, but I have to disappoint you, it is as we speak still unsupported :).

Comment: Note that this may require the use of `typename` keyword if `B` or `C` are themselves template parameters.