# templates and typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have some class like :

```
 template<int DIMENSION, typename T> Vector { ... }
```

Now, I want to specialize the typename and provide a new type using a typedef. I thus found an answer on StackOverflow at [C++ typedef for partial templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996914/c-typedef-for-partial-templates)

I thus did :

```
template < int DIMENSION> using VectorDouble= Vector<DIMENSION, double>;
```

This does not compile (error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition). Is this because my compiler (Visual Studio 2008) doesn't allow it, or did I miss something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you refer to says:

> If you have a C++0x/C++1x compiler

C++1x is not yet current, so most compilers don't support its features. In particular, VC++9.0 (VS2008) has almost no support for them. VC++10 (VS2010) does support *some* features, but I don't know if what you need is one of those.

Comment: It's not, unfortunately. We'll have to wait for the next release.

Comment: ok - I didn't know VC 2008 didn't have C++0x/1x features. Thanks! (9 more minutes to accept the answer)

Comment: @WhitAngl: It actually does support a few, like strongly scoped enums and some angle bracket parsing stuff. Just not this oe.

Answer (score 4):

Template typedefs are supported in the next Standard- that is, basically, only the really, really, *really* new compilers support it. Even the newest VS doesn't support it becaue, well, it's not new enough, that's how new C++0x is.

In C++03, then typically, you use a struct.

```
template<int dimension> struct vector_double {
    typedef Vector<dimension, double> type;
};
```

Now it can be accessed like

```
int main() {
    vector_double<5>::type vec_double;
}
```