# Partial template binding, create new template as type

Tags: c++, c++11, template-aliases

Is there some way to partially bind a template to parameter types?  For example, I have the following template:

```
template<typename T, typename Q> struct generic { };
```

And I have another template which takes a template class as a parameter, expecting to be able to create instances of it with the first type:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Impl>
struct wrapper {
    Impl<T> foo;
};
```

This would accept a simple template like `template<typename T>` without changes. What I want to do now is partially bind the `generic` template, specifying only `Q` and passing it to `wrapper`. Making up some syntax, perhaps something like this:

```
template<typename T> bound = generic<T,some_type>;
```

I know I can almost get what I want using inheritance:

```
template<typename T> bound : public generic<T,some_type> { };
```

I am hoping though to avoid this though as it causes issues with constructors and operators defined in the base class.

Comment: `template<typename T> using bound = generic<T,some_type>;` ? AKA "template-typedef" ?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, that looks good... I can't test it though since I'm on GCC 4.6 which doesn't support it yet. That probably means there is no earlier feature which does this.

Comment: That feature is also knowns as *Template Aliases* and according to [this chart](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) it's indeed supported since `4.7`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you can use **template aliases**

```
template<class X>
using Bind_CPP11 = generic<X, Y>;

template<class X, template<class> class Impl>
struct wrapper_CPP11
{
    Impl<X> foo;
};
```

In C++98/03, you can use simple [**class composition**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649726/819272) (I would not use inheritance here)

```
template<class X>
struct Bind_CPP03
{
    typedef generic<X, Y> type;
};

template<class X, template<class> class Impl>
struct wrapper_CPP03
{
    typename Impl<X>::type foo;
//  ^^^^^^^^ to extract dependent type
};
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8f594409c5ec1dd1eb98d8c2edf4b71f-b3a39f4e9c268c2df146ea17ecc4d5fd).

Comment: The composition requires `wrapper` would change how it references the type. I'm not sure if I can do that in my case, but the answer is still fine.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y yes, so if you upgrade to C++11, fixing the `wrapper` would be a TODO